# Efficient use of pandas dataframe.replace

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I'd like to remove text from the `NameAndID` column which appears in the `Name` column of a dataframe (`NamesAndIDs`) and put it in a new column called `IDOnly`. Sometimes however the text from `Name` doesn't actually appear in `NameAndID` and so I would like that to appear as a `NaN` in the `IDOnly` column.

e.g. I would like to turn the following dataframe:

```
Name            NameAndID             IDOnly

Lovely Place    Lovely Place 6D456    NaN
Great Town      Something 7GL2        NaN
```

into:

```
Name            NameAndID             IDOnly

Lovely Place    Lovely Place 6D456    6D456
Great Town      Something 7GL2        NaN
```

I have tried using `DataFrame.replace` in the following way:

```
NamesAndIDs['IDOnly'] = NamesAndIDs['NameAndID'].replace(to_replace = 
                    NamesAndIDs['Name'], value = '', regex = True)
```

My dataframe is large (125k rows) and this is taking a long time (gave up after 50mins).  I've tried timing it on a small random sample (1000 rows) and get a time of 500 ms. This suggests to me that something is going wrong.

Question: is there anyway of achieving my aim quickly?

I tried this on another dataframe  of size 25 times smaller and it ran in 6 seconds, so you would expect that on the current dataframe it would take 6 sec x 25 = 150 sec or 2.5 minutes.

Thanks in advance.

Rob

**EDIT**

I tried splitting my code up into blocks and it ran in about 1 minute.  So I suspect there was a memory usage issue.

```
numRows = NamesAndIDs.shape[0]
numSlic = 1000

for i in range(numSlic):
    LB = i*numRows/numSlic
    UB = min((i+1)*numRows/numSlic, numRows-1)
    ind = NamesAndIDs.index[LB:UB]  
    NamesAndIDs.loc[ind,'IDOnly'] = NamesAndIDs.loc[ind, 'NameAndID'].replace(to_replace = 
                    NamesAndIDs.loc[ind, 'Name'], value = '', regex = True)
```

This is strange as I'm running Yosemite OSX with 8GB RAM.  My actual dataframe is 8 columns wide all with text variables.  Each column entry is less than 256 characters long.  So 8*256*125000/10^9 = 0.25 GB.

Question:  Why does splitting my code into blocks make this run so much faster?

Comment: loc is very slow, will be faster with .ix in my experience. Someone once explained to me why this is, but I cannot remember.

Comment: That's interesting and your theory about memory sounds plausible.  In terms of processing power and speed, pandas advantage is really with numbers not strings, so you could even try doing this completely outside of pandas and see how it works (although you may still find storing in in pandas to be convenient, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Use string split?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'NID' : ['Lovely Place 6D456', 'Great Town Something 7GL2']})
df['ID'] = pd.Series([val[-1] for val in df['NID'].str.split()])
```

The assumption being that the ID is always present and always the last part of the string.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the ID bit might not be at the end or not be there at all.  I'm really just trying to remove the 'Name' variable from the 'NameAndID' variable if it's there.

Comment: I see. You could also do a regex. If the code will contain a number if it is present you could exploit that. I am thinking of ways of getting the code out rather than the name...